# Is it possible to use SendGrid free or bronze with CloudFlare's free plan?

Tags: ssl, email, sendgrid, cloudflare

I am using CloudFlare (free plan) for SSL and like it, the only problem is my emails are now not sending.  I have SendGrid configured in my rails application.

SendGrid documentation, https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/clicktracking_ssl.html, implies that I can only configure SendGrid with CloudFlare if I'm using their silver plan (80/month) because I need a white label domain.  White label domains are only available with the silver plan.

[image: SendGrid documentation]

Is there a way to configure the DNS records to send SendGrid emails without having to upgrade to the silver plan?  If not, is there another service I should switch to?

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. The SendGrid Whitelabeling options are only available for all Silver level packages and above. The Silver package offers more than just whitelabeling. Example, you can add dedicated IPs for sending for improved management of your sending reputation. More details about the different features: https://sendgrid.com/mkt/assets/pdfs/SendGrid_Pricing_Plan_Comparison_Chart_v7.5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the only way to achieve this via SendGrid is to pay for the domain whitelabeling feature. I believe this is true for similar services as well (mailgun, mandrill, etc), although prices may vary.

That said... if you're sending non-trivial amounts of email, it's worth paying for domain whitelabeling (regardless of which provider you're using). You'll want to start building domain level reputation as soon as possible, and maximize email deliverability.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem was w/ gmail yesterday.  I'm not sure why, but the emails actually were delivered properly everywhere but gmail.  Today gmail works fine too.

You can actually do this for free with SendGrid and CloudFlare, the only difference is you'll have a send via sendgrid.me next to your delivery email address, see screenshot below.

[image]

The benefits of white labeling your domain are in the other answers but 80 dollars a month for a startup with no funding and no customers seems really steep.

I'm also going to look into Amazon SES because it seemed easy to configure with CloudFlare and more affordable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remember CloudFlare will block all API requests made by sendgrid. Rules based on user-agent etc. are only available in Enterprise plans.